# Matlab Undefined function or method 'C' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, function, double, simulation, circuit

```
function simps()
A=[0,0];
B=[0,0]; 
set_param('circuit/LINE2','Capacitance',num2str(C(1)))
        sim('circuit')
    B=[Real,Reactive];
        A=[A;B];    
end
```

`C` is a matrix. It contains 10 variables. Like 1,10,50,100 random.It is in uF.
`circuit` is name of file
`Real Reactive` are the `to workspace` name.
`LINE2` is the name of the RLC branch. RLC branch contains only capacitance.

I am getting error

> "Undefined function or method 'C' for input arguments of type
>   'double'. "

I have searched stackoverflow, everybody talks about directory problem. But all my files are inside RUN directory.

I did

```
>> which C
```

It returned

```
C is a variable.
```

So I think the C is in directory path of matlab. So where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to do either of following

**a)** pass `C` as argument to function `simps()`

***OR***

**b)** evaluate `C` from workspace

`C = evalin( 'base', 'C' );`

inside the function before its use.

Also, use of `eval` and `evalin` is generally discouraged as it makes your code harder to follow and re-use.

**Tip :**

You may want to combine both like following

```
function simps(C)
if nargin == 0
    C= evalin( 'base', 'C' );
end
% Your code
```

Comment: Yes passing the variable as argument worked. But why does this error occured? When I was using a script, it worked fine, in function it didn't.

Comment: @Moz scripts normally get executed as if then are running directly from command windows thus have access to all workspace variables, however you can't use workspace variables simply inside in a function